# Join Multiple Select queries with where clauses for each

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, accounting, datepart

So I have a series of Amortization schedules, and I'd like to run a query to return the balances for the month of May on each schedule

My query right now, looks something like this

```
select ace.date, ace.balance, aacs.date, aacs.balance, 
axl.date, axl.balance, la.date, la.balance, 
mrh.date, mrh.balance
from 
(select *
from [Entity1]
where MONTH (date) = 05 AND YEAR (date) = 2017) as ACE
full join
(select *
from [Entity2]
where MONTH (date) = 05 AND YEAR (date) = 2017) as AACS
on ACE.GLCredited = AACS.GLCredited
full join 
(select *
from [Entity3]
where MONTH (date) = 05 AND YEAR (date) = 2017) as AXL
on AXL.GLCredited = AACS.GLCredited
full join
(select *
from [Entity4]
where MONTH (date) = 05 AND YEAR (date) = 2017) as LA
on LA.GLCredited = AXL.GLCredited 
full join 
(select *
from [Entity5]
where MONTH (date) = 05 AND YEAR (date) = 2017) as MRH
on MRH.GLCredited = LA.GLCredited
```

this is what it returns

```
    date     |  balance     |    date      |    balance   |    date      |    balance   |    date      |    balance   |    date      |    balance    | 
------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------  |
NULL         | NULL         | 2017-05-31   | 563275.00    | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | NULL          |
------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------  |
2017-05-31   | 896337.00    | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | NULL          |
------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------  |
NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | 2017-05-31   | 3746167.00   | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | NULL          |
------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------  |
NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | 2017-05-01   | 474774.00    | NULL         | NULL          |
------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------  |
NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | 2017-05-31   | 127987.00     |
```

Is there any way that you know of, that will return the data without the null values?

[Picture of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lgVs.jpg)

Comment: SELECT column_names FROM table_name WHERE column_name IS NOT NULL;

Comment: Tried that. Same results.

Comment: You need to specify precisely what you want the output to look like in terms of the input. All you've given us is a vague summary and a query that doesn't do what you want and an example of its output. We can't read your mind. Please also read & act on [mcve]. Also please use text whever possible--like instead of the that link.

Comment: I said I needed a query that would return the data without the null values... perhaps you overlooked. I believe that's pretty specific... if you can't help I'd prefer that you refrain from criticizing, especially if what you're asking me to do is right in the post.

Answer (score 1):

You would do this with a union not a join. Something like:

```
select date, balance
from [Entity1]
where MONTH (date) = 05 AND YEAR (date) = 2017) as ACE
union
select date, balance
from [Entity2]
where MONTH (date) = 05 AND YEAR (date) = 2017) as AACS
on ACE.GLCredited = AACS.GLCredited
union
select date, balance
from [Entity3]
where MONTH (date) = 05 AND YEAR (date) = 2017) as AXL
on AXL.GLCredited = AACS.GLCredited
union
select date, balance
from [Entity4]
where MONTH (date) = 05 AND YEAR (date) = 2017) as LA
on LA.GLCredited = AXL.GLCredited 
union
select date, balance
from [Entity5]
where MONTH (date) = 05 AND YEAR (date) = 2017) as MRH
on MRH.GLCredited = LA.GLCredited
```

Comment: Thats not working either as you typed it, the aliases were throwing it off. 

Once I corrected it, it shows a list of dates and balances which is better, but still doesnt help me identify the entity that the balance belongs to

Comment: Just add a static value column to each select like :

Comment: I thought of that last night and it's perfect. This is great. Thanks for your help Mike!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `UNION`:

```
Select * 
FROM
(
select 'ACE' as ScheduleName, date, balance from [Entity1]
union
select 'AACS' as ScheduleName, date, balance from [Entity2]
union
select 'AXL' as ScheduleName, date, balance from [Entity3]
union
select 'LA' as ScheduleName, date, balance from [Entity4]
union
select 'MRH' as ScheduleName, date, balance from [Entity5]
)u
where MONTH (date) = 05 AND YEAR (date) = 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily just add IS NOT NULL on all your sub queries.  Therefore the returns that you get from your sub queries will not include NULL

```
  ....
  from 
   from [Entity1]
   where MONTH (date) = 05 AND YEAR (date) = 2017 and *DATE is not null*) as ACE
  join
 (select *
  from [Entity2]
   where MONTH (date) = 05 AND YEAR (date) = 2017 *and BALANCE is not null*) as AACS
  on ACE.GLCredited = AACS.GLCredited
  join
```

Comment: Tried that. Returning the same results as above, surprisingly.

Comment: Did you try just doing a JOIN and not a FULL JOIN? If you run just 1 of the subqueries with DATE IS NOT NULL, does it still return with a NULL ?

Comment: When I run query as JOIN instead of FULL JOIN I get zero results
I also tried to run just 1 of the subqueries as you suggested, the result set does not change

Comment: Something is not right. The sub query should not return a NULL if written correctly.  Would you mind posting a sample of your database that you are working with?

Comment: Sure I just put a link to the photo in the original post